# To run Omnet++ from command prompt, how to solve liboppcmdenvd.dll is missing error?

Tags: omnet++

I want to run that Omnet++ project using command prompt. I am trying to execute the .exe file using the cmd prompt it is showing me the system error- "The program can't start because liboppcmdenvd.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem". 
I reinstalled the program but still it is showing the same error. So can anyone please tell me what is that .dll file and how I resolve this error? And also is there any way run Omnet++ from command prompt and write result to a file without opening the graphical simulation interface?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to run OMNeT++ simulation without Eclipse in Windows. Setting paths to OMNeT++ libraries as well as to MinGw binaries is most important.
I assume that:

- you use OMNeT++ 4.6
- OMNeT++ is installed in `e:\omnetpp\omnetpp-4.6`
- your model is called `wireless1` and is located in `e:\omnetpp\omnetpp-4.6\samples\wireless1`
- your model depends on `MiXiM 2.3`
- Mixim-2.3 is located in `e:\omnetpp\samples\MiXiM` and it is built

1.Append the following path to the Windows system PATH variable: `e:\omnetpp\omnetpp-4.6\bin;e:\omnetpp\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\mingw32\bin;e:\omnetpp\samples\MiXiM\src`

2.The list of directories with NED files in MiXiM has to be prepared. Do the following:

- open `mingwenv.cmd`
- in the mingw console type 
   `cd /e/omnetpp/omnetpp-4.6/samples/wireless1` 
  then
   `find ../MiXiM/ -name "*.ned" -printf '%h\n'| sort -u > list1.txt` 
  then
   `tr '\n' ';' < list1.txt > list2.txt`

3.In the `e:\omnetpp\omnetpp-4.6\samples\wireless1` directory create a new text file with the following content:

```
@echo off
wireless1.exe -u Tkenv -l mixim -n [CONTENT OF LIST2.TXT]  ..\simulations\omnetpp.ini
```

where after `-n` you have to paste the whole content of `list2.txt` (without the last ; and without `[`,`]`).
Then save this file as `standalone.bat` and just double-click on it to start simulation. Results of the simulation will be written to *.sca and *.vec files in `simulations\results`.
In order to run without GUI change `-u Tkenv` into `-u Cmdenv`.